# Issue with adding firebase analytics plugin to an existing app that has phonegap-plugin-push (firebase cloud messaging)

Tags: firebase, ionic3

My Ionic project has the foll. plugin:

```
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="2.2.3">
```

Above plugin is used to implement firebase cloud messaging - push notifications.

Now I am trying to integrate firebase analytics but I get an error when trying to install the firebase analytics plugin using "ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics". The error says - version of plugin @1.1.0 does not satisfy dependency plugin requirement @1.2.0. I dont want to force install so what is the best solution to this?

[image: error]